# Is there a way to access the checked value of a checkbox in a gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

So I have a template field with a checkbox and a hidden field in it.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAdd" />
       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfValue" Value='<%Item.SomeValue%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Using javascript, I want to able to look through to see which checkboxes are checked and get the corresponding value stored in the the HiddenValue control.

I know how to loop through the rows of a gridview and get a cell's innerText.  How would I go about getting a checkbox's checked and a hidden field's value?

Comment: Are you using jQuery on your project?

Comment: In some places, yes.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to find hidden field value from gridview on check changed of check box of gridview by javascript then you can use like below function.

```
   function IAmSelected(source, eventArgs) {
                if (source) {
                    // Get the HiddenField ID.
                    var hiddenfieldID = source.get_id().replace("chkAdd", "hfValue");// here you can add any control of your gridview row which value you want
                    $get(hiddenfieldID).value = eventArgs.get_value();
                }
      }
```

Comment: That would store the value of only one check box, wouldn't it?